# Android 4.4 Chrome cursor visible and Bootstrap fixed menu issue

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use fixed menu from bootstrap 3. When I select any text in the input and scroll page to bottom I get the pin in front of menu:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIh67.png

How can I fix it?

Comment: If the position of your cursor is set dynamically with some jQuery, you'll need to detect scroll and re-process its position on every page movement.

Comment: No, it's standart cursor and it's set manually by finger:)